# "Do I have my mobile phone inside?"- Is this sentence correct?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, verbs, sentence, questions

Is this sentence grammatically correct?

"Do I have my mobile phone inside the restroom?" or "Do I have my phone there(some place)?"--- One day I asked this question to my friend and he replied that the statement is not correct but didn't give me any reason and I couldn't find any proper justification online. I was confused as I just transformed the sentence "I have my mobile phone inside" into an interrogative one. Is it grammatically wrong?

Comment: "I have my mobile phone inside" implies to me that you have a mobile phone inside you. So the question "Do I have my mobile phone inside?" would appear to be asking someone else if you have a phone inside yourself, which seems odd.

Comment: In that sense "Do I have my phone there?" is it correct? Also I have edited my question accordingly.

Comment: Well yes "do I have my mobile phone inside the restroom" is grammatically correct. Just like "do I calculate my bicycle inside the restroom" is correct. I don't think you meant to ask about grammar. Just because something is grammatical, doesn't make it idiomatic. It's really the latter you want to know. And no, this is not idiomatic at all. Commonly a native speaker would simply ask, "is my phone in the restroom" or "have I left it there".

Comment: If your phone is in the restroom and you are not, then you don't "have" it. The normal question is _Is my phone in the restroom?_

Comment: It's unclear.  Are you intending to ask if mobile phones (or their use) are permitted inside the restroom?  If so, your question is phrased incorrectly.

Comment: Your sentence is grammatical but it's difficult to find a context where it would be meaningful, except perhaps as a repetition of a question that was asked of you. *What did you say? Did you ask, do I have my phone inside?*

Comment: I down-voted because you haven't answered our questions.

Comment: It's just a phone. Nobody is going to bother pointing out that it's wireless.

Comment: @HotLicks what is your question? Why do I get downvotes?

Comment: ***What do you want the sentence to mean???***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Do I have my mobile phone inside the restroom?" or "Do I have my
>   phone there(some place)?"--- One day I asked this question to my
>   friend and he replied that the statement is not correct but didn't
>   give me any reason and I couldn't find any proper justification
>   online. I was confused as I just transformed the sentence "I have my
>   mobile phone inside" into an interrogative one. Is it grammatically
>   wrong?

*Note that what follows is my answer but I have duplicated some of what was said in the comments.*

---

You sentences are *grammatically* correct but they don't have a sensible meaning.

If you *have* your phone then you don't need to ask where it is because "have" implies that it is with you.

"I have my mobile phone inside." - If you have a phone inside then either you have it inside you (you have swallowed it) or you have it inside something you are carrying with you (inside a container).

---

A possible question is, "Is my mobile phone inside the restroom?"

Answer (score -1):

I can guess what you ment. What I could say is:

“Is my mobile phone still in the restroom?”

Comment: Except people would just say "phone".

Answer (score -2):

There's nothing wrong with **inside** there except that it would usually be accompanied by **with you** in that particular question.

> Do you have your mobile phone inside with you?

There, **inside** refers to the interior of some place which is important in context.

A pedestrian taking a shortcut through an alley hears banging on the metal door of a restaurant kitchen:

> Hello?
>
> --Let me out! The security door locked automatically and the kitchen is on fire.
>
> There's no way for me to open it from the outside. Do you have your mobile phone inside with you?
>
> -- Yes, I do.
>
> Take some pictures for social media while I run and get help.

But in other statements it would be idiomatic for the word to stand alone:

> I left my umbrella inside.

There, **inside** means "indoors", that is, inside the house or inside some other building which one has exited.

> That was a pretty good restaurant! But it's gotten a lot colder while we were having lunch.
>   -- That reminds me, I left my coat inside!